# Sci Fi Novel where alien commander raises dignitary's daughter and falls in love with her when she grows older?

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a novel I used to have quite a time ago, I never finished it but this is what I remember.

A galaxy is inhabited by alien races and one alien (who was a commanding officer and a confidant to a dignitary) is tasked with raising said dignitary's daughter after an attack by an enemy force.

Years pass and the Commander grows fond of the girl who is now clever and beautiful and wishes for his help to extract revenge on the enemies who had wronged them so long ago.

The cover of the hardcover edition had a sexualized woman sitting on a throne on a desolate planet at night, a shooting star in the background along with the alien's blueish-green face subdued among the stars.

Notes of interest: late 80's/Early 90's novel, Alien commander is tasked to defend dignitary and daughter during transport, transport falls under attack, alien takes daughter and pet monkey thing into an escape pod, alien commander grows to love the girl after many years pass, basic revenge plot.

Yes it is an actual hardcover book, no it is not an erotic novel.

Comment: Sounds like it could be one of [Catherine Asaro's](http://www.catherineasaro.net/works/38) books or short stories.

Comment: I saw this plot when it was called - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mask_of_Zorro

Comment: Something that doesn't come across clearly. You say the "commander" is a member of an alien race with a blue-green face according to the cover art, but you don't clearly say that the "dignitary's daughter" is human. Nor do you say she isn't! The way you kept stressing the commmander's "alien" nature, I found myself thinking the *girl might* be the orphaned daughter of a human dignitary, but you never say that. Was she human?

Comment: it's describes her as "humanoid", not explicitly human, even though the cover art sure looked like a human female.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be "[Triple Detente](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/263431.Triple_Detente)" by Piers Anthony?

[image: Front cover of Triple Detente] [image: Another alternate cover] [image: Alternate Cover]

> Earth and Kazo have created a unique peace. Kazo administers Earth, and Earth controls Kazo. Nothing is really complicated until both humans and Kazos discover the existence of a third intelligent race in the galaxy and try to bring them into the newly developing peace.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. That's a good first attempt of an answer, but you may want to consider adding why you think this book is what OP is looking for (details, etc.).

Comment: None of the covers are remotely a fit, and it really doesn't sound like a revenge plot.